# How to reference a maven project in gradle project for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, project, gradle

I'm using eclipse and I'm new to gradle.
I have imported a maven project [OrientDB](https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb) into the eclipse workspace.
Then i created a new java project in this workspace, and a gradle build file.

How do I reference the maven multiprojects to use them inside my own java-eclipse-project managed with gradle? Can some one provide me a code snippet for the gradle build file please?

I tried to manipulate the classpath, but that didn't work.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
classpath {
  file {
     beforeMerged { classpath ->
             classpath.entries.add "/orientdb"
         }

      }
    }
}
```

Think I misunderstood the docs, but have no clue how to do it right.

Note: I can not use the libraries from maven repository, because I need the new Version.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [file dependencies](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub%3afile_dependencies) like in the following example. The eclipse plugin should pick up those dependencies and add it to your project's classpath within Eclipse.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'orientdb', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. What have I to do when I want to include a complete maven-eclipse project as source? I don't want to build this referenced maven-project with gradle, only import it to the eclipse project for development.

Comment: Do you really need the dependency as Eclipse project? I'd recommend building the artefacts with Maven and putting them in your Maven local repository. Or, if you don't want to do that build the JARs and use them as file dependencies.

Comment: You are right, I should use file dependency. But it would be nice to know.